# Cannot programatically set value in text box in input group

Tags: angular, angular7

In my HTML page I have an input group used to set values the amount from, amount to, and amount equal to.  I am trying to set the amount from value programatically  when the page loads in my angualr code.  The value in the model is set fine but it does not show on the UI in the input box.  What do I need to do so it shows there?

Here is my HTML for this input group:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="max-width: 6%">
                <label class="col-sm-3 text-sm-right col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">&gt;=</span>
                        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amountFrom" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="amountFilter.amountFrom">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">&lt;=</span>
                        <input  type="text" name="amount" id="amountTo" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="amountFilter.amountTo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Or=</span>
                        <input  type="text" name="amount" id="amountEqual" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="amountFilter.amountEqual">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my code in my Angular component called in ngOnInit():

```
            this.amountFilter.amountFrom =  50;
```

When the page loads and after the code above is called a shown below the amount from field is not set:

[image]

However the actual model value has been set as shown in my debugger:

[image]

Comment: can you please make this project in stackblitz and share that link with us so that we will give sure solution.

Comment: is there any errors in the console... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('amountFrom') as HTMLInputElement
ele.value = '50'
```

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] considered deprecated. The best practice is use reactive forms (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)
used it you can set value use method setValue(value);

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error. I have created a sample app take a look at that you may get an idea. [Sample app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmc45c)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help. I have manged to get this working by changing the names of each input text box to amountFrom,. amountTo and amountEqual to.